# In java, is it bad practice to use Runtime Exception as a super "break" through function calls?

Tags: java, runtimeexception

Sometimes, there is a series of function calls, where at middle you determined the result and you want to stop the whole function chain middle way. In such case, is the following way bad?

```
public ResponseObject composeResponse {
   try {
       ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();
       processA(response);
       processB(response);
       processC(response);
       processD(response);
          .
          .
          .
       return response;
       } catch (SomeFlagException e){
       return response;        
       }
   }
```

where for each process function, it is also like

```
public void processA(ResponseObject response){
    minorProcess1(response);
    minorProcess2(response);
    minorProcess3(response);
      .
      .
      .
}
```

In some particular conditions, say minorProcess3(), have such case that the result is determined and the rest of the processes are not wanted. Assume this happens in lot of the minorProcesses.

```
public void minorProcess3(ResponseObject response){
    //some process
    if (someFlag){
        //want end the process and return the result
        throw new SomeFlagException(); //SomeFlagException extends RuntimeException
    }
}
```

My mind is telling me no, for it is not an "exception" but an expectable outcome. And I heard that unchecked Exception should only be throwed when it cannot be reasonably resolved. But I could only think out this way to make code clean, otherwise the code will have to cascade the conditions check all the way back to the base function.

EDIT: Adding info on my situation. It is a web project, so it suppose to return proper response with payload. Sometimes the request should be responded by a 204/40x. No payload required, and therefore further process is not necessary and should be abandoned.

Comment: Why can't you just immediately `return`?

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- Do you mean return at "if statement"? It will only go to the end of minorProcess3, but there is more minorProcess in processA, and after processA there will be processB,C and so on. I want all those process to be ignored.

Comment: It's very difficult to say for certain with such a vague description. If I personally had to solve this problem with no further information, I would use the `Either` type from [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/), which allows you to designate a value as either "Left" or "Right" and to at any point in a pipeline change the value from Right (continuing processing) to Left (skip further processing), at which point it falls through to the pipeline's end or finishing steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing so is really bad practice.

An exception means that some method could not fulfill its contract. The approach you ask about turns this to the opposite: use an exception to mean early success.

Although it will technically work, it's so much against the intended meaning of exceptions that I have to strongly recommend against using such an approach.

> And I heard that unchecked Exception should only be throwed when it
> cannot be reasonably resolved.

IMHO, this is bad advice. As the one throwing an exception, how can you know if some caller method up the call stack can continue successfully after your failure? That's only decidable in the context of the caller (whether it has a fallback strategy for the failure or not), and rarely depends on the type of exception. It's not your responsibility to decide that, and even if you tried to make that decision, it would most probably turn out wrong.

E.g. for your caller, it typically doesn't matter if you failed because of `NullPointerException` or `IOException`, just to name two prominent examples of the unchecked / checked categories. What matters, is that you failed, and maybe the caller knows how to proceed after your failure.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* throw an Exception as part of your algorithm's logic. Exceptions must indicate that something *we did not want* went wrong

A more clean approach is to have `process(ResponseObject)` and `minorProcess(ResponseObject)` methods return a `boolean` value indicating whether the process of the response should continue further.

See example:

```
public boolean processX(ResponseObject response)
{
    boolean shouldContinue;

    shouldContinue = shouldContinue && minorProcess1(response);
    shouldContinue = shouldContinue && minorProcess2(response);
    shouldContinue = shouldContinue && minorProcess3(response);
      .
      .
      .

   return shouldContinue;
}
```

When using the `&&` operator, if the first condition is false, the second is not evaluated.

Example of minorProcess:

```
/**
*
*/
public boolean minorProcessX(ResponseObject response)
{
    //some process
    if (someFlag)
    {
        //want end the process and return the result
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should rename your `continue` variable, as it is a keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MCEmperor. You are right. I renamed it to `shouldContinue`.

Comment: The code you posted will not compile because of a few minor problems.

Comment: Editted. It should work now @RalfKleberhoff.